# Python Zip function flipping first and second list?

Tags: python, list, zip

I realize the code might not be the cleanest but just throwing it together quick before cleaning up and I'm running into an issue where the zip() at the end is not zipping the two lists correctly. Not only is the initial start of the list starting with the 'CurrencyValue' instead of 'CurrencyName' as instructed, but randomly throughout the list it flips them? And with no discernable pattern to me. I can't imagine why this would be happening.

```
import requests
import json

CurrencyName, CurrencyValue = [], []

test = requests.get("https://poe.ninja/api/data/CurrencyOverview?league=Ritual&type=Currency&language=en")

testJson = json.loads(test.text)

with open("test_jsonAllCurrency.json", "a") as output:
    json.dump(testJson, output, indent=1)

with open('test_jsonAllCurrency.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for name in data['lines']:
        strippedName = [x.replace(' ','').replace("'","") for x in name['currencyTypeName']]
        strippedName = "".join(strippedName)
        CurrencyName.append(strippedName)
        CurrencyValue.append(name['receive']['value'])
    
CurrencyList = [{t, s} for t, s in zip(CurrencyName, CurrencyValue)]

print(CurrencyList)
```

Expected output:

```
[{'MirrorofKalandra', 21733.97142857143}, {'MirrorShard', 1089.0}, {'MavensOrb', 544.5}, {'TemperingOrb', 396.0}, {'AwakenersOrb', 346.5}, {'HuntersExaltedOrb', 99.0}, {'WarlordsExaltedOrb', 99.0}, {'CrusadersExaltedOrb', 99.0}, {'PrimeRegradingLens', 99.0}, {'ExaltedOrb', 99.0}, {'TailoringOrb', 99.0}, {'RedeemersExaltedOrb', 55.0}
```

Actual output:

```
[{21733.97142857143, 'MirrorofKalandra'}, {1089.0, 'MirrorShard'}, {544.5, 'MavensOrb'}, {396.0, 'TemperingOrb'}, {346.5, 'AwakenersOrb'}, {99.0, 'HuntersExaltedOrb'}, {99.0, 'WarlordsExaltedOrb'}, {'CrusadersExaltedOrb', 99.0}, {'PrimeRegradingLens', 99.0}, {99.0, 'ExaltedOrb'}, {'TailoringOrb', 99.0}, {'RedeemersExaltedOrb', 55.0}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `zip`, You are using a `set` object, `{t, s}` . set objects *are inherently unordered*, any order that you see is the result of an implementation detail. If you need order, use an ordered data structure, e.g. a `list`, `tuple` etc etc It sounds like you *intended* to use a list, so you want `[t, s]` instead, note, you could just use `list(zip(...))` if you don't mind tuples... `zip` already creates tuples.

Comment: Son of a... Good catch. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: Did you mean to create a *dictionary*: `{t: s for t, s in zip(...)}`? Or simply `dict(zip(...))`

Answer (score 0):

Juanpa.arrivillaga was right; I simply goofed and was using curls instead of brackets. I guess I just needed another set of eyes!